# Biholomorphic mapping of $\tan(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm supposed to solve this question:

> 6. Show that the function $\tan$ maps the vertical strip $-\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$ biholomorphically to $\dot B(0,1)$

It is obvious that $\tan(z)$ will be holomorphic in this vertical strip. To prove injectivity and surjectivity I tried to write:
$$\tan(z) = \frac{\sin(2x)+\sinh(2y)i}{\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x)}=w$$
With $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$, working this out I get:
$$(\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x))u=\sin(2x)$$
$$(\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x))v=\sinh(2y)$$
I should get now that for $w$ in the open unit disc, there is a unique $z$ in the vertical strip, but I have no clue how to proceed. I hope someone can help me out. Please tell also if there is a better/faster way to prove bijectivity than my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\tan(z) = \frac {\sin z}{\cos z} 
= \frac {\frac {1}{2i}(e^{iz} - e^{-iz})}{\frac {1}{2}(e^{iz} + e^{-iz})}
= \frac 1i \frac {e^{2iz} - 1}{e^{2iz} + 1}
$$
is the composition of the thee mappings
$$
 z\to u = 2iz, \quad u \to v = e^u, \quad v \to w = \frac 1i\frac{u-1}{u+1} \, .
$$

- The first maps the vertical strip $-\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$ biholomorphically to the horizontal strip $-\frac{\pi}{2}<y<\frac{\pi}{2}$.
- The second maps the horizontal strip biholomorphically to the right half-plane.
- The third (a Möbius transformation) maps the right half-plane biholomorphically to the unit disk.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it now :D

Answer (score 0):

I diagrammed this mappings with Maple software. hope it works for you.
This is the area on page z:[image]

[this is the area $-{{\pi}\over{4}}\leq x\leq{{\pi}\over{4}}\ ,\ -2\leq y\leq 2$]

This is a diagram of function $e^{2iz}$:

[image]

Now we apply the linear fractional transformation ${{z-1}\over{z+1}}$ to the  function $e^{2iz}$:
[image]

Finally, we rotate this diagram by 90 degrees clockwise:
[image]