# Proving that $\tan(z)$ is bijective

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Prove: $\tan(z)$ is bijective over the domain/codomain$$\{z\in\mathbb{C}: -\pi/2<Re(z)<\pi/2\}\to \mathbb{C}\setminus\{i,-i\}$$ I had no problem showing injectivity of the tangent function but as soon as I started dealing with surjectivity I had a problem. I was thinking about using the Intermediate value theorem in a way but not sure how to apply it in this case.

Comment: yes, $\tan(\pi/2)=-\infty$ and $\tan(\pi/2)=\infty$

Comment: $\tan(z)=\dfrac{1}{i}\left(\dfrac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\circ \exp(iz)\right)$ might be a useful fact.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072329/42969.