# $f$ be a holomorphic function in $\{|\mathrm{Re}(z)|<\pi/4\}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1$. Show that $|f(z)|\leq |\tan(z)|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $\{|\mathrm{Re}(z)|<\pi/4\}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ . Show that $|f(z)|\leq |\tan(z)|$.

I think that this is solved by Schwarz Lemma by considering a function $g:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \{|\mathrm{Re}(z)|<\pi/4\}$ as $z=g(w)=\tan^{-1}(w)$ (Is it well defined?)

Now the function $f\circ g:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ fixes zero, thus by Schwarz Lemma $|f(g(w))|\leq |{w}|$ i.e. $|f(z)|\leq |\tan(z)|$.

Am I right? How do I prove the validity of the function and that the range lies in the region?

Thanks

Comment: To show that $arctan$ is well-defined, try showing that $\int_0^z\frac{1}{1+w^2}dw$ is analytic in your region.

Comment: @Gary: Just mentioning that there is `\operatorname` which can be used to typeset operators as in $\operatorname{Re}(z)$, compare  e.g. [What's the difference between \mathrm and \operatorname?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48459). Apparently it makes not much visual difference *here.*

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thank you for the feedback. I am usually using that one but as you noted it does not make too much difference here and it was faster to typeset mathrm.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\tan(z) = \frac 1i \frac {e^{2iz} - 1}{e^{2iz} + 1}
$$
maps the strip $S = \{ z \mid -\pi/4 < \operatorname{Re}(z) < \pi/4 \}$ *biholomorphically* to the unit disk $\Bbb D$, see for example [Biholomorphic mapping of $\tan(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072329/biholomorphic-mapping-of-tanz). Therefore a holomorphic inverse mapping $g: \Bbb D \to S$ exists.

Now you can proceed as in your question: Apply the Schwarz Lemma to $f \circ g: \Bbb D \to \Bbb D$ and conclude that $|f(g(w)| \le |w|$ for all $w \in \Bbb D$.

Finally, for $z \in S$, we can set $w = \tan(z)$ and get $|f(z)| \le |\tan(z)|$.

Equality holds if and only if $f \circ g$ is a rotation, i.e. if $f(z) = \lambda \tan(z)$ for some $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| = 1$.