# $-\cos(z)$ is a biholomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem statement: Show that $f(z) = -\cos(z)$ is a biholomorphism between the semi infinite strip $\{(x,y): 0<x<\pi, y>0\}$ to the upper half plane.

To show holomorphic, we just notice that the imaginary part magnitude of $e^{iz} = e^{-y}e^{ix}$ is strictly smaller than $e^{-iz} = e^{y}e^{-ix}$. But is there an easy way to show biholomorphism without using complicated injective/surjective argument?

Technique from [Biholomorphic mapping of $\tan(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072329/biholomorphic-mapping-of-tanz) does not seem to work in this case.

Comment: one way is to show injectivity which is easy using the cosine difference formula and the fact that the sine is zero only at $k\pi$ and then show that the boundary of the strip is mapped to the real line; this shows that the image of the strip is one of the two half-planes and checking at some value (eg $\pi/2+i$) shows the image is the upper half plane so the map is onto; the inverse is holomorphic automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(z) = - \cos(z) = g(e^{iz})$ with
$$
 g(w) = -\frac{w^2+1}{2w} \, .
$$
$z \mapsto e^{iz}$ is a biholomorphic mapping from the half-strip $\{(x,y): 0<x<\pi, y>0\}$ to the semi-disk $\{ z : |z| < 1, \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0 \}$.
The rational function
$$
 g(w) = \frac{(w-1)^2+(w-1)^2}{(w-1)^2-(w-1)^2} = \frac{\left( \frac{w-1}{w+1}\right)^2+1}{\left( \frac{w-1}{w+1}\right)^2-1}
$$
is a composition of “elementary” functions (Möbius transformations and squaring). These are biholomorphic mappings from the semi-disk onto the second quadrant, then onto the lower half-plane, and finally onto the upper half-plane.