Is the complex tangent Injective?
So if we consider the Analytic function $f(z)=\tan(z)$ when $z\in \{z\in\mathbb{C}\text{ : } -\pi/2<Re(z)<\pi/2 \}$ is it injective ? Its derivative is non zero however this only guarantees local infectivity. How could I check something like this. Similarly what happens when we consider the extensions of the other trig functions on a strip in which their real restriction is injective. My idea was to extend their associated inverses on the complex plane try to work with the existence of a right inverse but I am not sure if that argument is correct since I am not sure if I can even get complex arcsin,arccos...
Thanks in advance for your help.

Non-zero derivative doesn't matter for determining whether a complex function is $1-1.$

$$\tan z=\frac1i\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{e^{2iz}+1}$$ Note the $z\mapsto e^{2iz}$ is one-to-one on that domain, then $w\mapsto \frac 1i\frac{w-1}{w+1}$ is one-to-one on the range of $e^{2iz}.$

@ZoeAllen or $z>-\frac\pi2.$

@ZoeAllen I fixed it, yes I meant $Rez>-\pi/2$

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072329/42969
